# Can't move imported 3D model in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I imported a custom 3D model in my scene via script, and i can visualize it.
The piece of code I used is:

```cs
private GameObject myObj;

void Start()
{        
    myObj = Resources.Load<GameObject>(path_to_model);
    Instantiate(myObj);
    myObj.transform.position = Vector3(1.5f, 0, 2.3f);
}
```

I can see the object in the correct location, but if I try to move it inside the update() section using a coroutine with Lerp, it doesn't move.

**NOTE:** I already tried the script using a primitive shape (a sphere) and the object moves as required.

Comment: Please include the code you have for moving the object.  Using a coroutine in Update sounds incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myObj` should not be assigned to the model itself, but to the clone of that model.

```cs
private GameObject myObj;
void Start()
{
    myObj = Instantiate(Resources.Load<GameObject>(path_to_model));
    myObj.transform.position = new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 2.3f);
}
```